# how avoid 401 error everytime with axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios, jwt, token, http-status-code-401

I have a project with react and an java spring boot api. For connect to the api, after SignIn with google login, i do this :

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { signInRoute } from '../../routing';

export function SignInGetService() {
    axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_SERVER_URL + '/url', {})
        .then(response => { });
}

export async function SignInPostService(token) {
    return await axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_API_SERVER_URL + '/mySignInUrl', { "token": token })
        .then(response => {     
            axios.defaults.headers.common['X-AUTH-TOKEN'] = response.data['data'];
            return response.data['data']
        }).catch(function(error) {
            if(error.response.status == 500){
            window.localStorage.removeItem('userFromStorage');
            window.location.reload()
            }
        });
}
```

in app.tsx my code is :

```
interface AuthContextType {
  user: any;
  signin: (userMail: string, callback: VoidFunction, userObject: Object) => void;
  signout: (callback: VoidFunction) => void;
}

let AuthContext = React.createContext<AuthContextType>(null!);

function AuthProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<any>(window.localStorage.getItem('userFromStorage'));

  let signin = (newUserMail: string, callback: VoidFunction, newUserObject: Object) => {
    return fakeAuthProvider.signin(() => {
      setUser(JSON.stringify(newUserMail));
      window.localStorage.setItem('userFromStorage', JSON.stringify(newUserMail));
      callback();
    });
  };

  let signout = (callback: VoidFunction) => {
    return fakeAuthProvider.signout(() => {
      setUser(null);
      window.localStorage.removeItem('userFromStorage');
      callback();
    });
  };
  const value = { user, signin, signout };
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  if (user != null) {
    let r = SignInPostService(JSON.parse(user).token).then(() => {
      setIsLoading(false)
    })

  }
  if (user != null && isLoading == false) {
    return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
  }
  if (user == null) {
    return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;

  }
}

export function useAuth() {
  return React.useContext(AuthContext);
}



function RequireAuth({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) {
  let auth = useAuth();
  let location = useLocation();
  if (!auth.user) {
    return <Navigate to="/SignIn" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
  }

  return children;
}
```

So after this, normally everytime I do a request my X-AUTH-TOKEN is suppose to be well set.
And actually it's work. But sometimes, not often but enough for being annoying, I have an 401 error.
And If I refresh the 401 error disappear.
Do you know where it can come from ?
Thank you all.

I expect that the X-AUTH-TOKEN is set everytime.

Comment: Could it be possible that `response.data['data']` is `undefined` sometimes? Add `console.log("token", response.data['data'])` and check if it `null`/`undefined`.

Comment: You either use `await` or `then`. Can you post your full function code?

Comment: Try adding axios config: `{withCredientials: true}`

Comment: Sounds like you should add an interceptor to refresh your auth tokens when they expire

Comment: i will add an interceptor but sometimes it happend just after the SignIn. I mean, I signIn and then I redirect to an other page and on this other page i have 401 error. It's rare but it happend.

Comment: after check with console.log, response.data['data'] is never null or undefined. It's hard to redo the error cause it doesn't happend a lot.

Comment: I edited the answer for you can see more code.